# What does おやすみちゃー mean?

Tags: phrases

I saw a native Japanese speaker post this on Twitter, I believe that `おやすみ` means vacation or holiday, but I was unable to figure out the phrase from the context.

Comment: You can't understand this use of おやすみ as a combination of お and やすみ.  It's an abbreviation for [おやすみなさい](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%8A%E3%82%84%E3%81%99%E3%81%BF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%95%E3%81%84&dtype=3&dname=2na&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=00600400), which is derived from お＋やすみ＋なさい, but has become a single word meaning "good night!"

Comment: Could you share with us a link to this twitter post?

Comment: I tried to dig it up, but was unable to find it. The entire text of the tweet is `おやすみちゃー( ＾＾)`

Comment: I googled "おやすみちゃー" and it seems like some people are using おやすみちゃー or おやすみちゃーい to say おやすみなさーい (probably jokingly, or to sound childlike or cute). Kids often pronounce おやすみなさい as おやすみなちゃい, and they even dropped the な.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`やすみ` means vacation or holiday.  `おやすみ` is usually said to mean `おやすみなさい`, which means "good night".  I don't know what the `ちゃー` part means.  Can you provide more context (or the whole tweet itself)?

Comment: The entire text of the tweet was `おやすみちゃー(  ＾＾)`

Comment: Hmm, I have no idea then.  Could be an inside slang that person uses.  Like I sometimes say `おじゃすみ〜ん` for `おやすみ`.

Comment: perhaps ちゃ is a dialect of [仙台]{せんだい} or [北九州]{きたきゅうしゅう} area.
cf. うる星やつら 1話 うわさのラムちゃんだっちゃ http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLzST737yEc at 6m28s, 8m05s and so on.

Answer (score 0):

could it also be a contraction of 休みちゃういますー or similar?

行ってしまう　・　行ってしまいます are the same after all & Japanese people love 略語.